# Data from mysql to php to javascript and html for use with chartist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a little project going to log temperatures and such to a MySQL database, and I'd like to provide for accessing that info from anywhere.
My initial crude attempt worked pretty well (simply a PHP file getting the MySQL data into an HTML table)

Now I'd like to use some pretty graphs in this project and I've failed despite many many many hours of googling.

Here's the PHP and js/HTML files.
(edit: removed all the mysql stuff to focus on the php->js connection)
this is the php file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<body>

<?php
$phpvar = ( {labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'], series: [[8, 13, 21]] });

$jsvar = json_encode($phpvar);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Next, the js/HTML page where I'm trying to pull the data from the PHP script in so that it can be displayed using chartist...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<! include chartist>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<! include ajax jquery >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="ct-chart ct-double-octave" id="chart1"></div>

<div id="testdiv"> 
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">   

    $.getJSON('stackphp.php', function(data) {
       var jsvar = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(jsvar);



  var sample= {
    labels: ['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    series: [
      [8, 13, 21],
      [1, 2, 3]
    ]
  }


var chart = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', sample);


</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

@T.Shah... Interestingly, this code does display a sample graph sucessfully...IF if remove the three lines 1    $.getJSON('stackphp.php', function(data) {
       var jsvar = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(jsvar);`

Leaveing those three line in however, breaks the whole page... even thought the jsvar variable isn't used in the chartist function. Not sure why that is.

This project is making it clear to me how little I've actually dabbled in web code before. If I can get a fingertip's worth of grip on what I'm missing, I'll pound away at this as much as needed.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

so this project has taught me just tons about javasript, php, and the rest of the webstack.
I’ll try to outline the answer to my original question in case someone else finds this via google.

First, getting data out of mysql using php was pretty easy. Here’s that code…

Setting up a convenient set of variables…

```
<?php
   $hostname = "localhost";
   $username = “mysqladminusername”;
   $password = “mysqladminpass”;
   $db = “tablename”;

   $dbconnect=mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$db);

   if ($dbconnect->connect_error) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . $dbconnect->connect_error);
        }
?>
```

then pulling the data….

```
<?php
   set_time_limit (60); //needed to prevent timeout error mysql reports the unlimited script takes ~30sec 

   $query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER by idcolumnname DESC limit 2000")
      or die (mysqli_error($dbconnect));
?>
```

Then reading the data and putting into an html table…. and creating php arrays with the contents of each mysql column.

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo
   "<tr>
    <td>{$row[‘col1name’]}</td>
    <td>{$row[‘col2name’]}</td>
    <td>{$row['col3name’]}</td>
    <td>{$row[‘col4name’]}</td>
    </tr>\n";

$phpcol1[] = $row[‘col1name’];
$phpcol2[] = $row[‘col2name’];
$phpcol3[] = $row[‘col3name’];
$phpcol4[] = $row[‘col4name’];
}
?>
```

At this point the php arrays are formatted as normal php “associative arrays”… something like this….
array(10) { [0]=> array(1) { [“col1name”]=> string(3) "658" } [1]=> array(1) { [“col1name”]=> string(3) "657" } [2]=> array(1) { [“col1name”]=> string(3) "658" }
….which is not very useful since chartist doesn’t understand it.

So we need to convert it to the format chartist expects, e.g.   [232,345,4545,343,235,32]
(keep in mind that this array is one of two that chartist requires, it needs an array of “labels” and an array of “series”… and then the chartist demo code puts those together and uses them in the final bit of code that actually creates the chartist graph.)

We do this conversion using json encoding. 
This can be done in stages, using variables to separate the code for readability, or as a oneliner for compactness.
The compact version is the method I chose in the end.
e.g….

```
<script type=“text/javascript”>
var jsonlabelsdatavariable = <?php echo json_encode($phpcol1) ?>;
var jsonseriesdatavariable = <?php echo json_encode($phpcol2) ?>;
```

//comment…here I found it useful to print the formatted array data to the screen so I could see the change with my eyes. To do this, I created an html dviv element like this….
`<div class="container" id=“showmethedata”></div>`…. 
in the body of the html page then I put the array data in with the following code…

```
document.getElementById(“showmethedata”).innerHTML
```

//comment… while I was testing this, I used placeholder data in the chartist demo code so that I could switch back and forth between the working demo code, and the broken custom code, and use developer tools to see the problems. so below you’ll see that the chartist demo code starts out filled with my placeholder data, then gets emptied out, and then overwritten with the real data from the json variable.

//This is the chartist demo code…..(notice the line feed, I was testing for characters that would break the chartist display, since a problem I had at that time was all the label data being shown in one point of the graph. Turns out this problem was not from bad characters, but that I was pushing my label data into a single label array element.

```
var data = {
             labels: ['2222-02-13_09:12:00','2018-02-13_09:11:00','2018-02-13_09:10:00','2018-02-

13_09:09:00','2018-02-13_09:08:00'],
             series: [
                       [5,2,4,2,0]
                     ]
            };
```

//Now I blank the placeholder arrays…

```
data.labels.length = 0;
data.series.length = 0;
```

//now I fill the arrays with the real data…note that two methods are used. this is due to the formatting that chartist expects… the labels array is a single array with elements… while the series array contains an inner array, and that inner array contains the elements. using the push method on the labels array resulted in the labels array being shows as a label for a single data point on the graph.

```
data.labels = data.labels.concat(jsonlabelsdatavariable);
data.series.push(jsonlight);
```

//finally we can build the chartist graph…

```
new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, { width:10000, showArea:true, reverseData: true, });
```

//and lastly, we close the javascript tag.

```
</script>
```

I’ll also note i woulnd up using a few custom functions that edited the contents of my php array elements to do things like remove spaces, add or remove quote marks around each element, etc… but i don’t think any of that was actually necessary.
e.g.

```
function addquotes ($element){
   return "'{$element}'";
}
$withquotes = array_map("addquotes", $sourcearray);

function killspace ($anothersourcearray){
   return str_replace(' ' , '_', $anothersourcearray);
}

$phpkillspace = array_map("killspace", $anothersourcearray);


$unspecial = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/", "", $finalsourcearray );
```

What an adventure.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was flowing @David 's code and had problems in few spots, so for reference, here is my complete code:

```
<?php
//here is connection information
require "cont.php";
$db = db_connect();

$upit = "SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT * FROM meteo LIMIT 1000
            ) sub
            ORDER BY id ASC";
$rezultat = mysqli_query ($db, $upit);
db_disconnect($db);
$label = array();
$series = array();
if ($rezultat != null)
{
    $i = 0;
    $j = 0; //vairable for sciping few database enteries.
    while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezultat))
    {
        $j++;
        if ($j == 1)
        {
            $t = date_create($red['at']);
            $label[$i] = date_format($t, 'H:i');
            $series[$i] = array($red['dht_temp'], $red['bmx_temp']);
            //$series[$i] = array($red['id'], $red['dht_temp'], $red['bmx_temp'], $red['hum'], $red['press'], $red['w_speed'], WindDirectionToString($red['w_dir']));
            $i++;
        }
        // how meny entries to scip
        if($j == 10) {
            $j = 0;
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
          var data = {
            labels: <?php echo json_encode($label) ?>,
            series: <?php echo json_encode($series); ?>
          };
          var options = {
            width: 1000,
            height: 500
          };
          new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data, options);
        </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that '100.php' file return data in the format that chartist expects. If you can make sure of that, then your html file could be like this. Then remove the random data part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<! include chartist>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
<! include ajax jquery >
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="ct-chart ct-double-octave" id="chart1"></div>

<div id="testdiv"> 
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
    $.getJSON('100.php', function(data) {
       var jsvar = JSON.parse(data);
       console.log(jsvar);

//          jsvar = {
//            // random test data just to build a visible chart
//            labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
//            // random test data just to build a visible chart
//            series: [
//              [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
//            ]
//          };


      // Create a new line chart object where as first parameter we pass in a selector
      // that is resolving to our chart container element. The Second parameter
      // is the actual data object.
      new Chartist.Bar('.ct-chart', jsvar);       

    });

</script>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks T.Shah...
I've used your code and played around some more and I'm still hitting a brick wall.
I'll post some simplified test code  to see if it helps. (edit... code block in comments don't work so well... I'll edit the question instead).

Comment: Okay, changes to the codeblocks are finished. The php file is now just a dummy where I'm trying to force a properly formatted array (because getting the mysql data into the proper format is indeed another challenge). So far I have not yet been able to access any php variables from the js file.

Comment: In your PHP file, after the code completion, you have to echo the result. Then only it will be available as ajax response data. So you must write like this - $jsvar = json_encode($phpvar); echo $jsvar;   Also you have to create json object properly in php. Refer to this - https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-json-parsing.php  . Once you have $phpvar in proper format, then the whole thing will make sense.